# Looking for a good followup to the Stanford AI course

Tags: machine-learning, references

I took the original Stanford AI course and got an immense amount out of it. I got a poor score since I did not have a great deal of time to work out all the problems.. But what I really enjoyed about the course was getting a grasp of the new techiques, way beyond the conventional statitistcs..

I'm looking for a way to get to the next level. The course really did not provide a good reference for reviewing the subject. The big book by the course authors (Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach by Norvig and Russell) (which I have) is too complex for me.

I try to do all my work in Python and I am making some headway in getting the tools, Sci-py, scikit learn, NLTK. Pandas (am currently reading Data Analysis with Python, by Mckinney, excellent). and more.. But I'm in need of references to help me leap from the conceptual level to actual implementation , including proper tool selection and problem selection and definition, that is, sort of a cook book approach.

This question may be too open ended,, but it expresses my dilemma. The whole space is quite open ended, and I'm looking for references to help me navigate through it.

What references (accessible) might you suggest?

Comment: Coursera Probabilistic Graphical Models class is going on now.

Comment: There are several courses available, I just don't have the time and for the time being think I need more reading before heading back for courses.. I just learn better that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wanted to refer you to the Statistical Learning book but I wanted to be sure that it wasn't your text.  It was written by Stanford Statistics faculty Trevor Hastie, Jerome Friedman and Rob Tibshirani. [Here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387848576) is a link to it on amazon.

Comment: Also can be downloaded at Tibshirani's homepage http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/

Comment: I had downloaded it but not yet read, with your recommendation will move up the list! Thanks for the pointer.. There is so much out there it is hard to even determine what to do next, without guidance. Thank you!

Comment: FYI I'd possibly mark this as answered but want to see if others have ideas, as well want to at least skim the book you mentioned. So I'll keep checking!

Comment: You could still give me an upvote even if you decide to check someone else's suggestion.

Comment: That book really is wonderful, read it start to end.

Answer (score 1):

I'm finding that the machine learning course from Coursera/Andrew Ng/Stanford is really great. It has a balance of statistics, AI, linear algebra, programming. The motivations/intuitions that are given in the video lectures get me pumped to solve some problems.